# Bulk Collect From Oracle and fill to a DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, bulk

In my project I need to get over 10,000,000 records from Oracle database, for improving efficiency. I write a SP and use BULK COLLECT, BULK COLLECT is fast for selecting, isn't it?
The procedure is below:

```
create or replace type type_bulk as TABLE OF number(10);
/
create or replace PROCEDURE getbulk(returns OUT type_bulk) 
is
BEGIN
SELECT origseq BULK COLLECT
   INTO returns
   FROM Indicationinfo;
end;
/
```

Then I can execute SP like below in PL/SQL:

```
declare
    origbulk type_bulk;
begin
    getbulk(returns => origbulk);
    dbms_output.put_line(origbulk.count);
end;
```

It works fine.

origbulk is a table(or array). So the question is:

1.How to exec SP like above in C#;
 2.How to fetch origbulk to C# app;

I try it like below(I use OleDb driver, and Provider is"OraOLEDB.Oracle.1")

```
 string commText = 
"DECLARE ? type_bulk;\n" + 
"BEGIN\n" + 
"getbulk(returns => ?);\n" + 
"END;"; //here is right?
 myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(commText, myAccessConn);
 myAccessCommand.CommandType=CommandType.Text;
 OleDbParameter pout = new OleDbParameter("origseqbulk", ???what type, no OleDbType.Array, 10);
```

Any advice?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What are you going to do with ten million numbers in C# that you cannot do in PL/SQL?

Comment: @APC,the C# app need to display those records, so I think I should get them to memory of the C# app first. Do you have any advice?

Comment: why don't you just fetch the results of the query: `SELECT origseq FROM Indicationinfo`

Comment: Displaying 10 m records is not a good idea(it will take a lot of time, if will ever succeed). You should handle the scroll event of the object that will display the data to load new rows as the user scrolls.

Comment: How are you going to display 10,000,000 records at one time? I'd think that you'll need to scroll or page the results so just retrieve the record you need for immediate display and fetch the rest on demand.

Comment: My advice would be to not attempt displaying ten million records.  Ho human user is going to look at them.  So, what really are you trying to do?  What is the business requirement?  Focus on that, rather than trying to tune the pointless retrieval of way too many records.

Comment: Hi,APC. There have two purposes get records from DB. The first is display them, according your and above others advice I will page those records then display them.The Second is I need to send Msgs(composed by origseq) to other app as soon as possible(the send fucation is very fast), So I must get all records as soon as possible and compose them to msgs, and send them. Do you hanv any better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Re: advice - reading 10 million rows of data into memory is not a way to be "more efficient".  This will be very slow, both because the database will take a while to return 10m rows, and because it will take another long time (and lots of memory) to cram these values into a control, if that's what you're doing.  To give you an idea of what I mean, I just read 100 *thousand* rows from one of our bigger tables, and found that it took about 26 seconds.  Nothing complicated, just

```
SELECT A_COLUMN FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ROWNUM <= 100000
```

OK, that's one percent of your 10 million rows.  Now, I'll never claim that our database is highly performant, but if it's representative of your situation and if the access time scales linearly it would take something on the order of 40 minutes or so to read in your 10 million rows.  I suppose that if this is a big batch process maybe that would be OK.  If, on the other hand, you've got a user sitting there waiting to see some data displayed they'll probably give up before the data ever shows up on their screen.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: yes,you are right. There have two purposes get records from DB. The first is display them, according your and above others advice I will page those records then display them.The Second is I need to send Msgs(composed by origseq) to other app as soon as possible(the send fucation is very fast), as you said, bottleneck is get data from db, So I think I should speed up get data from DB, Do you have any advice?